# Joomla multilingual !! Joomfish plugin content is not updating

Tags: php, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomfish

I'm using the joomfish plugin for creating the multilingual website. I installed the joomfish successfully. After the proper installation of joomfish and language package, in the front-end of the webpage when i click the flag to switch to the language only the author and posted dates getting changed but not the full content. Same like the right and left side modules also in the default language(english). Please could any one can suggest me any good documentation or give me the solution for the above problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried to translate your articles by going at `Components>Joom!Fish>Translation` in the backend (select your language and `Contents` as filters) and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes. First i like to convert my articles to other language but the title of the language is coming in the respective language but not the content. How i can make the content also to come in the respective language??

Comment: Make sure that in "Components>Joom!Fish>Content Languages" all the languages you are translating into are ticked as active.

Comment: Yes!! everything is active but when i add the content into the translate body i'm choosing the respective language too . In preview also i can able to see the content in the respective lang. but after i saved the article the inserted content itself not presenting in the article page when i try to edit the article!!

Comment: Have you ticked "published" under the language dropdown in the article translation page?

Comment: yes it's already published!! Here the problem i found is when i insert the translated content it's not updating in the database. Because when i open again the content is empty!!

Comment: click on the "save" button when you add the translation and then "apply"

Comment: Yes!! It's working Great!! Thanks for your help!! And how i can change the modules languages also??

Comment: i accepted your answer!! Could u explain my prev question or comment?

Comment: thanks for that. I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "modules languages". Try posting another question in SO putting some more specifics.

Answer (score 2):

For joomfish 2.1.7:

1. Open administrator\components\com_joomfish\models\ContentObject.php
2. Go to line 616
3. In the IF statement replace

   ```
   && $fieldContent->reference_field=="fulltext"
   ```

with

```
&& ($fieldContent->reference_field=="fulltext" || $fieldContent->reference_field=="introtext")
```